# Spark - Is it possible to broadcast a function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing

This is probably a dumb question but I wanted to be sure whether it's possible to broadcast a function in Spark and not only data.

I know I can broadcast data, for example

```
scala> val myList=List(1,2,3)
myList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> sc.broadcast(myList)
res112: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[List[Int]] = Broadcast(7)
```

but how about a function? For example,

```
scala> def sum(a:Int):Int={
     | val b=a+1
     | b
     | }
sum: (a: Int)Int

scala> sc.broadcast(sum(_))
res113: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[Int => Int] = Broadcast(8)
```

Is this actually broadcasting my method `sum`? Somehow this means that every node now has a "copy" of the method `sum` and maybe I could parallelize some jobs which make use of the method `sum`, maybe by broadcasting some data as well. Is this correct?

Comment: you don't need to broadcast a function. every function you use in a RDD is serialized inside it.

Comment: @shay__ So if I try something like `sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3,4,5)).map(i=>sum(i))`, does it mean that my function `sum` will be serialized automatically so that every node now has a "copy" of `sum` (roughly speaking)?

Comment: @antonioACR1 yes, closures are serialized automatically. This is also true for data like your list. Broadcasting is only important if your data is large and you want to avoid that this data is serialized for every task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes!** It is possible to pass the complete function in a broadcast variable.

If your algorithm(function) is changing based on some action/event/time you can use this approach. The new function will be executed with the remaining data.

```
def doubleFunction(a: Int):Int={a*2} // function returns the double of input data
val broadcastFunction = sc.broadcast(doubleFunction(_))


val data = sc.parallelize(1 to 10000,4) // sample data

val output1 = data.map(x=>{
    val localDoubleFunction = broadcastFunction.value
    localDoubleFunction(x) // using function passed in broadcast variable
}).reduce(_+_)
//output1: Int = 100010000
**// Runtime: 78ms**


val output2 = data.map(x=>{
    doubleFunction(x) //local broadcast function
}).reduce(_+_)
//output2: Int = 100010000
**//Runtime: 200 ms**
```

[Spark Web UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIRQt.png)

Comment: I'm getting the error `java.io.IOException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Error constructing instance of class:` when I try to run `output1`. Do you know what might be the reason? If I collect the RDD then it works

Comment: Also, could you tell me what `reduce(_+_)` is doing in your code?

Comment: I guess you are running the code on yarn. And for the example above I've used aggregation function. Hence collect would be required. I am not exactly sure for the Kyro exception!

Comment: `reduce(_+_)` is equivalent to `reduce( (a,b) => a+b )`. So it basically sums all the numbers but in a distributed way(spark) !

Comment: I ran your code in spark-shell using a Cloudera VM, although I had the same error several times before running other code...

Answer (score 1):

Broadcasts are generally used for small amounts of data that can easily live on the executor's memory. The reason its done is for caching copy of the data so that whenever the actual tasks takes place, this small data doesn't have to be moved across executors. You can read more here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/broadcast/Broadcast.html

Now if your idea is to write your own function and use that function for some parallel compute , you should be looking at UDFs ( https://medium.com/@mrpowers/spark-user-defined-functions-udfs-6c849e39443b ) .

Comment: I think UDF is used if I want to apply my own function on a dataframe, however I'm not dealing with dataframes at the moment.